# C# - Automatically close a form after x minutes

Tags: c#, multithreading

Situation: I wrote a WinForms application which users access via an RDP.  The nature of the application is such that two users cannot run the application at the same time.  The problem we're having is that folks will forget to close out of the app, essentially locking other users out.

What I'd like to do is add functionality to automatically close the app after x minutes.  I realize that I need to use threading for this since marking time in the main thread would freeze up the app.  I don't have a critical need to detect activity/inactivity, but if that's trivial to do, I'd definitely like to know.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Try a `Timer` or `await Task.Delay()`.

Comment: If you are using Javascript too, you can set timeout and close the popup after defined interval

Comment: So, what have you tried? I don't see a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about closing the app from inside the WinForms app itself...use a Timer as suggested by SLaks:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr.Tick += delegate {
            this.Close();
        };
        tmr.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;
        tmr.Start();
    }

}
```

If you wan't to get fancier and close after X minutes of inactivity, then write your own [IMessageFilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) that resets a Timer whenever mouse/keyboard activity occurs (WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, etc.).  You register your filter with `Application.AddMessageFilter()` in the Load() event of your Form.

Comment: What does delegate this.close do? Why delegate?

Answer (score 1):

This may help, just put this together, it will close the form 1.5 seconds after the button1 is pressed. you could change this to any time after form load.

```
    public void testc()
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 1500;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); 
        t.Start();

    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tick");
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testc();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class starting from the Idle_Mind's reply, that create a message with another feature : Opacity

- Add a Form to your project and call it VanishingMessage.
- Add a text label to the Form, i called it : testo
- Add the event PAINT to the form.
- Copy and paste this code
- When you call the class set the the message and seconds as parameters, like required.

I personally suggest to set the FormBorderStyle to NONE.

```
public partial class VanishingMessage : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr2;
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a message windows. 3 sec is the suggested time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="messageText">Message</param>
    /// <param name="vanishingSeconds">Showing time</param>
    public VanishingMessage(string messageText, int vanishingSeconds=3)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        double elapsedTime = 0;
        testo.Text = messageText;
        double vanishingMilliSeconds = vanishingSeconds * 1000;

        // message dimensions
        this.Width = testo.Width + 50;
        this.Height = testo.Height + 50;

        //text position
        testo.Location = new Point((this.Width / 2) - (testo.Width / 2), (this.Height/2)-(testo.Height/2));

        //first timer
        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr.Tick += delegate {
            tmr.Stop();
            tmr2.Stop();
            tmr.Dispose();
            tmr2.Dispose();
            this.Close();
        };
        tmr.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(vanishingSeconds).TotalMilliseconds;
        tmr.Start();

        //second timer
        tmr2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr2.Tick += delegate {
            elapsedTime += 50;

            if (elapsedTime >= (vanishingMilliSeconds * 65)/100)
                this.Opacity -= 0.05f;

        };
        tmr2.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50).TotalMilliseconds;
        tmr2.Start();
    }

    private void VanishingMessage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.DarkRed);
        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkRed);
        Rectangle r = this.DisplayRectangle;
        r.Width -= 1;
        r.Height -= 1;
        g.DrawRectangle(p,r);
    }
}
```

Here how to call the class :

```
 VanishingMessage vm = new VanishingMessage("your message",3);
 vm.Show();
```